# How to get words from a varchar column and their frequency of occurrence in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, innodb

I have a `varchar(255)` column with `FULLTEXT` index. I need a query to get the most frequent words in the entire column as

```
Word    Frequency
key1    4533
key2    4332
key3    2932
```

*Note 1:* I would prefer to skip common words such as prepositions, but it is not critical as I can filter them later. Just mentioned if it can speed up the query.

*Note 2:* It is a table with over a million rows. It is not a regular query but should be practically fast.

If you even give a hint how the query should look like, it will be a great help.

Comment: Do it in application code, not SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really something that is easy to do in MySQL.  The full text index is not available for querying.  One thing you can do is extract words.  This is a bit painful.  The following assumes that words are separated by a single space and gets the frequencies of the first three words:

```
  select substring_index(substring_index(t.words, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as word, count(*)
  from t cross join
       (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
       ) n
       on n.n <= length(t.words) - length(replace(t.words, ' ', '') + 1
  group by substring_index(substring_index(t.words, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) 
  order by count(*) desc;
```